# python numpy square of matrix does not work

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matrix

I'm trying to change an image to a matrix. An image is loaded using OpenCV-python and successfully converted to NumPy matrix. Now, I have to use each pixel's square value as NumPy matrix, however, it does not give the correct result. I checked three methods to get a square matrix of NumPy matrix: `np.square(mat)`, `mat*mat`, `np.power(mat, 2)`. Those are worked successfully when I use an example array like : `numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`

But! As shown below, it does not give correct value when I use NumPy matrix converted from the OpenCV image.

For example, B value at [0, 0] pixel is 80 (below example) and square matrix value is 0 for all three methods. What's the problem?? Of course, the value the I want is 80*80 = 1600.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. because the format of cv is numpy.array(int8), the max value is 255
2. you can change the type to numpy.array(int32/64), the value will be right
3. as follows:

   B = B.astype(np.int32)